# PHP MySQL Get column names While iterating through all records

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   //How to echo column names and values here?
}
```

Is it possible to echo a table's column names and values while iterating through the entire table in a `while` loop?

Comment: print_r($row); what do you get ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use foreach loop

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     foreach($row as $key => $value) {
         print "$key = $value <br />";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this.. column_name is the same name u used in the table

```
echo $row['column_name'];
```

Comment: The user is asking how to get column names from a `select * ...` query which means he doesn't know what column he is looking at at the time. Your answer will return the column data, not the name.

Comment: It seems you've not understood the question.